# Handle no internet with HttpClient

Tags: windows-runtime, dotnet-httpclient, windows-phone-8.1

I have a windows phone runtime app that uses the HttpClient to make web request. How can I handle a connection exception (no internet).

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

First thing you can do before Http request:

```
    using Microsoft.Phone.Net.NetworkInformation;

    private void CheckInetConnection()
    {
        if (NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable() == true)
        {
            //Internet avalaible
        }
        else
        {
        //No connection available
        }
    }
```

and for exception handling of HttpClient [check this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh781241.aspx)

response.StatusCode will give you the status of response.